# Chrome extension for sending messages on twitch

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, twitch

I started to learn chrome extensions, I wanna make an extension with a list of phrases to send in twitch chat.

I have no intention of using the twitch api.

The first message is sent as it should, but the next ones nothing happens.

There's a log that shows that messages arrive on the page, I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

This is what I have:

**manifest.json**

```json
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Default Messages",
    "version": "0.1",
    "offline_enabled": true,
    "background": {
      "persistent": false,
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
    "content_scripts": [{
      "matches": ["*://*.twitch.tv/*"],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }],
    "page_action": {
      "default_title": "Default messages",
      "default_popup": "popup.html"
    }
  }
```

**background.js**

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((msg, sender) => {
  if (msg.from === "twitch" && msg.subject === "chat") {
    chrome.pageAction.show(sender.tab.id);
  }
});
```

**content.js**

```js
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
  from: "twitch",
  subject: "chat",
});

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((msg, sender, response) => {
  if (msg.from === "defaultMessages" && msg.subject === "newMessage") {
    console.log(msg);
    let input = document.querySelectorAll("textarea")[0];
    let buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");
    input.textContent = msg.content;
    input.dispatchEvent(new Event("input", { bubbles: true }));

    buttons.forEach((button) => {
      if (button?.dataset?.aTarget == "chat-send-button") {
        button.dispatchEvent(new Event("click", { bubbles: true }));
      }
    });

    response({
      from: "twitch",
      subject: "messageSent",
      id: msg.id,
    });
  }
});
```

**popup.js**

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  let tab_id = undefined;
  chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, (tabs) => {
    tab_id = tabs[0].id;
  });

  document.querySelectorAll("button").forEach((button) => {
    button.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
      if (!e.target.disabled) {
        let content = e.target.textContent;
        let id = e.target.id;
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(
          tab_id,
          {
            from: "defaultMessages",
            subject: "newMessage",
            content,
            id,
          },
          (resp) => {
            document.getElementById(resp.id).disabled = true;
          }
        );
      }
    });
  });
});
```

**popup.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="./popup.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="container">
         <div class="card mt-1" style="width: 15rem;">
            <div class="card-body">
               <div class="btn-group-vertical">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="hello">Hello</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="hi">Hi</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="how">How are you doing?</button>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing from "*textContent*" to "*value*" solved the problem, I don't know why.

**content.js**

```js
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
  from: "twitch",
  subject: "chat",
});

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((msg, sender, response) => {
  if (msg.from === "defaultMessages" && msg.subject === "newMessage") {
    console.log(msg);
    let input = document.querySelectorAll("textarea")[0];
    let buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");
    input.value = msg.content; // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< this 
    input.dispatchEvent(new Event("input", { bubbles: true }));

    buttons.forEach((button) => {
      if (button?.dataset?.aTarget == "chat-send-button") {
        button.dispatchEvent(new Event("click", { bubbles: true }));
      }
    });

    response({
      from: "twitch",
      subject: "messageSent",
      id: msg.id,
    });
  }
});
```